# how to set passcode with Koolistov Passcode xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, passwords

I´m an XCode newbie; so please be patient.

I am trying to secure my iOS app with a password - I have used github.com/Koolistov/Passcode for the base code.

When the app starts it works perfect and ask for the password. **I try to setup a new password** but it doesn't work. Please can anybody help.
At the moment the password code is "0000"

Update - code:

```
- (void)passcodeController:(KVPasscodeViewController *)controller passcodeEntered:(NSString *)passCode {
  if ([passCode isEqualToString:@"0000"]) {
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  } else {
    controller.instructionLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%@ -wrong PW.", @""), passCode];
    [controller resetWithAnimation:KVPasscodeAnimationStyleInvalid];
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code for us to look at and provide some more info? It's hard to help with just a three sentence description.

Comment: i only us this for the moment: - (void)passcodeController:(KVPasscodeViewController *)controller passcodeEntered:(NSString *)passCode {
    
    if ([passCode isEqualToString:@"0000"]) {
        
        self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }  else {
        controller.instructionLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%@ - wrong PW.", @""), passCode];
        [controller resetWithAnimation:KVPasscodeAnimationStyleInvalid];
        
        
    }
  }

Comment: You don't need to call [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; as you cannot even show the passcode view controller without the window having been loaded already. Apart from that, make sure the self.viewController is not equal to nil.

Comment: I try to setup a new password but it doesn't work. At the moment the password code is "0000"

Answer (score 0):

`if ([passCode isEqualToString:@"0000"])` will always compare to `0000`. You must keep track of the passcode you have set, and compare to that value instead of comparing to `0000`.

Comment: Yes, i know. my problem is how to set a new one?